# How many times has the Major Questions doctrine been invoked by higher US Courts?

Tags: legal-terms, us-supreme-court, legal-doctrine

In [West Virginia v. EPA](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/21pdf/20-1530_n758.pdf) the court invokes the "major questions doctrine," as part of it's justification for blocking what would otherwise have been landmark climate policy.  [This article](https://www.akingump.com/en/news-insights/supreme-court-invokes-major-questions-doctrine-in-west-virginia-v-epa-to-limit-agency-authority-to-tackle-climate-change-with-implications-for-rulemakings-across-the-regulatory-landscape.html#:%7E:text=For%20the%20first%20time%2C%20the,strike%20down%20an%20agency%20rule.) claims that it's the first time the doctrine has been invoked but since it's invoked by name, one has to assume it's defined and/or described somewhere else - at least once.

From whence does this court doctrine arise, and how many times has it been invoked in a SCOTUS or Appellate Circuit opinion?

Comment: Don't have time to write an answer at the moment, but the Congressional Research Service has a good and recent report on the topic. https://crsreports.congress.gov/product/pdf/LSB/LSB10745